# styling individual rows in a Vuetify data table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Can I apply different styling for a specific row in a data table?

This is my code:

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
          v-model="selected"
          :search="search"
          :no-data-text="mensagem"
          select-all
          :rows-per-page-text="linhasPorPagina">
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <td>
              <v-checkbox
                primary
                hide-details
                v-model="props.selected"
              ></v-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.apresentante }}</td>    
        </v-data-table>
```

For example, I want to apply a red line when the `Id > 4`

Comment: Did you tried to add :class with proper condition to template? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: The <tr> tag is not exposed in the data-table component, so a class can't be added directly within the template.

Answer (score 26):

You can now use vuetifys data table item-class property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    row_classes(item) {
        if (item.calories < 200) {
          return "orange"; //can also return multiple classes e.g ["orange","disabled"]
        } 
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [{text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name'},
                { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      ],
      desserts: [{name: 'Frozen Yogurt',calories: 159,},
                 {name: 'Ice cream sandwich',calories: 237,},
                 {name: 'Eclair',calories: 262,},
                 {name: 'Cupcake',calories: 305,},
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.css'>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :item-class= "row_classes"                  
      class="elevation-1"
    >
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.4/dist/vuetify.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can actually wrap your `<td>` elements within a `<tr>` element. Then you can use Vue style binding to determine whether you want classes applied or not.

```
<template>
  <tr v-bind:class="{'active-class-name': isActive(item)}">
    <td>Woo</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

It renders out the `tbody` block with a `row (tr)` with applied class names and the child columns contained within.

Comment: I get `Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Answer (score 11):

I was also trying to style rows in a vuetify data-table but the above answers didn't have everything I needed to make it work. **Using Vuetify v2**

I wanted to add a class to a row when a certain condition was met.

```
<v-data-table  
   :headers="myHeaders"
   :items="myItems"
>
  <template v-slot:item="props">
    <tr :class="{'my-class': props.item.current > props.item.total}">
      <td>{{props.item.current}}</td>
      <td>{{props.item.total}}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

---

```
...
// js portion of the component (computed prop)

myItems() {
    return [
      {
        current: 101,
        total: 100
      },
      {
        current: 45,
        total: 100
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the whole row to have a red line (or in my example a red background), you'll need to wrap the three td in a tr. If you just want it on the id cell, then you can add

```
<td class="text-xs-left" :style="{backgroundColor: (props.item.id > 4 ? 'red' : 'transparent' ) }">
 {{ props.item.id }}
</td>
```